Find and delete files from unix directory of multiple patterns
I need to delete files from a unix directory having patterns like 'bkp', 'backup', 'bak'.
Basically I want to delete all the backup files.
Files in the directory:
A001.txt_bkp
A001.txt
A002.csv_backup
A002.csv
A003.csv
A003_bak.csv

I want to keep below files
A001.txt
A002.csv
A003.csv


What is your operating system. Is it really UNIX? Which one? Or is it actually Linux?

With bash modern shell:
printf 'rm %s\n' *@(bkp|backup|bak)*

Replace printf 'rm %s\n' with rm, when happy with the output.
This use extglob capability.

Extended globs: shopt -s extglob allow you to say things like "all files that do not end in .jpg". See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Probably worth mentioning rm -- *@(bkp|backup|bak)* since the printed commands won't work if the file names have newlines.

I would use find for this:
$ find . -iname '*_backup' -o -iname '*_bkp' -o -iname '*_bak.csv'
./A001.txt_bkp
./A003_bak.csv
./A002.csv_backup

Here the . parameter means "from the current directory", but you could easily give it the full path to a directory containing files.
And -iname (a non-standard, but fairly common extension) means "case insensitive name".  The -o is "or"; for stringing multiple names together.
Once you're happy that there's no false-positives, wrap the conditions in parentheses and add -delete (another common though non-standard extension) to remove them:
$ find . '(' -iname '*_backup' -o -iname '*_bkp' -o -iname '*_bak.csv' ')' -delete

The standard equivalent¹ would look like:
$ find . '(' -name '*_[Bb][Aa][Cc][Kk][Uu][Pp]' -o \
             -name '*_[Bb][Kk][Pp]' -o \
             -name '*_[Bb][Aa][Kk].[Cc][Ss][Vv]' \
         ')' -exec rm -f {} +


¹ Except for the fact that -delete implies -depth to process files before the directory that contains them and contrary to rm would also delete matching directories if empty.

I find it puzzling that you need to find them and delete them.  It would seem sufficient to simply delete them.  The rm command does "the finding" for you:
rm -- *_bkp *_backup *_bak.csv

If you mean that you're not certain whether you really want to delete these files, then you may be looking for the ls command instead of rm.  Or if you're almost certain you want to remove those files, use rm -i instead of rm:
$ rm -i -- *_bkp *_backup *_bak.csv
remove A001.txt_bkp? y
remove A002.csv_backup? y
remove A003_bak.csv? y
$ ls -1
A001.txt
A002.csv
A003.csv

In most shells, it's a trivial operation to do an ls first, and if you approve the deletion of those files, up-arrow and change ls to rm.

"The rm command does "the finding" for you" -- No, in rm *_bkp *_backup *_bak.csv it is the shell who does "the finding".

Beware that in shells such as zsh, fish or bash -O failglob, if any of the *_bkp *_backup *_bak.csv glob fails to match, the command will be aborted and no file will be removed, in zsh, use rm -- *_b(kp|ackup|ak.csv), in fish rm -- *_b{kp,ackup,ak.csv} and in bash -O failglob -O extglob: rm -- *_@(bkp|backup|bak.csv)

@KamilMaciorowski, and that's also why you need the -- (which I've since added to the answer) to avoid problems if any of the filenames that the shell expanded the globs to starts with -.

@StéphaneChazelas Yes, I've adopted the habit of always using set -- and often needing to use cat -- even if filenames simply begin with a +.     I'll try to expand that practice.         @KamilMaciorowski Very true. Thank you.
